# Should I stringify part of document, that are not used in the query

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with document similar this:

```
{
  name: 'Foo',
  age: 25,
  extraInfo: {
    // very big, complex with many level nesting, and different between document.
  },
}
```

I only query document based name, age properties. I don't care what about extraInfo property. But it's very complex. I do not know whether it reduces the performance of the query process. What do I do with extraInfo. Should I stringify and compress it before insert into collection.?

Comment: It really should not make any difference unless you would run into the the [limitation of nested levels](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Nested-Depth-for-BSON-Documents). Of course there is also the [`BinData` type](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/bson-types/) for any arbitrary Binary storage of data. Which is a lot more efficient than storing a "string", and you don't need to "parse" data when you read it back when you do.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn .

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid stringifying embedded documents as this makes them impossible to use later down the line. I understand that there is no current requirement for the data to be used but who knows what requirements tomorrow will bring. It's better to plan for the future than block yourself in a corner.

It'll will most likely be the same amount of performance if you're creating strings of your embedded objects compared to serializing them in to BSON.

Comment: Thanks @kevin-smith. I can see "serializing them into BSON" is MongoDB's job behind scene, I don't need do anything but inserting them into collection normally?

Comment: Shouldn't need anything else, will just work out the box